# Need help installing ubuntu and I can't figure out how to stop live-booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm currently trying to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10. (I DON'T want to use ubuntu as a live USB)
I have a Dell XPS 13 9370.
I've made a backup of my system onto a spare HDD.
I've partitioned my main SSD with more than enough room for ubuntu (~100 GB)
I have ubuntu ready to boot on a USB stick.
I go into the BIOS, set the system to boot off of the USB stick.
I don't know how to install Ubuntu onto my computer instead of live booting it.
Thanks, HenriHawk

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booting off the Live USB and choosing "Install Ubuntu" at the wecome screen yet?

There are quite a few good guides on how to install Ubuntu around, for example [this one](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if it will work for me yet, because I don't have access to my computer right now, but I hope it does. Thanks!

Comment: I really like this one: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: No problem. If you get stuck in the process, this is the place to ask :)